# How to save changes if main window was closed?

Tags: blend-files

I have opened view in separate window, then closed main window without any warning. Now when closing separate window I get

[image]

Winthout any propose to save.

How to save then?

Comment: Ctrl-S is the save shortcut

Comment: He probably created another window in the same file by `Shift` + Dragging the corner of a view.